# Android BitmapDrawable Constructor Undefined

Tags: android, image, bitmap, inputstream, drawable

I'm trying to load an image from the web.  The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Resources res = getResources();

InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();

BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, is); 
// Error: The constructor BitmapDrawable(Resources, InputStream) is undefined
```

The last line produces an error as if the constructor doesn't exist.  However, the documentation says the following:

---

BitmapDrawable(InputStream is)
This constructor is deprecated. Use BitmapDrawable(Resources, java.io.InputStream) to ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density.

BitmapDrawable(Resources res, InputStream is)
Create a drawable by decoding a bitmap from the given input stream.

---

So, I'm at a loss.  Either this should work and I've got something set up wrong or I need to find another way to load the image from the web.  Does anyone know why this code doesn't compile or suggest a better way to load the image (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor was added since API Level 5, so I guess you are using an older API level thus you get that error. Try using Android 2.1 (eclair) or newer or don't use that constructor.

I just tried this and it worked:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(is);
```

Comment: I think that's it.  Thanks.  I am using API Level 4 so my application will work on phones that have not upgraded yet.  I'm not sure how important the "Resources res" is to how the image will be displayed.  In other words, what does "ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density" mean?  If it's important enough that I should use it for phones that have API Level 5 or above, how does an Android programmer typically handle such a case?

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html